# Problem with setjmp/longjmp

Tags: c, linux

The code below is just not working.
Can anybody point out why

```
#define STACK_SIZE 1524

static void mt_allocate_stack(struct thread_struct *mythrd)

{

    unsigned int sp = 0;
    void *stck;

    stck = (void *)malloc(STACK_SIZE);

    sp = (unsigned int)&((stck));
    sp = sp + STACK_SIZE;
    while((sp % 8) != 0)
    sp--;

#ifdef linux

    (mythrd->saved_state[0]).__jmpbuf[JB_BP] = (int)sp;
    (mythrd->saved_state[0]).__jmpbuf[JB_SP] = (int)sp-500;
#endif

}

void mt_sched()

{

    fprintf(stdout,"\n Inside the mt_sched");
    fflush(stdout);

    if ( current_thread->state == NEW )
     {
         if ( setjmp(current_thread->saved_state) == 0 )
         {
            mt_allocate_stack(current_thread);

            fprintf(stdout,"\n Jumping to thread = %u",current_thread->thread_id);
            fflush(stdout);
            longjmp(current_thread->saved_state, 2);
         }
         else
         {
            new_fns();
         }
      }
}
```

All I am trying to do is to run the new_fns() on a new stack. But is is showing segmentation fault at new_fns().

Can anybody point me out what's wrong.

Comment: In the future, please format code in your questions by indenting the block by four spaces (or equivalently by selecting it and clicking the 101010 icon).

Comment: You should not go poking inside jmpbuf values.  If you don't know what it does and why it does it, you simply should not do it.

Comment: Did you run it under gdb? What instruction is causing the segfault?

Comment: I ran the gdb this is the output of that 

 Jumping to thread = 1
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00b156a7 in mt_sched () at src/mt_internal.c:140
140 new_fns();

It seems that the code is unable to run in the newly created stack.

Answer (score 2):

Apart all other considerations, you are using "&stck" instead ok "stck" as stack! &stck points to the cell containing the POINTER TO the allocated stack

Then, some observations:

1) setjmp is not intended for this purpose: this code may work only on some systems, and perhaps only with som runtime library versions.

2) I think that BP should be evaluated in some other way. I suggest to check how you compiled composes a stack frame. I.e., on x86 platforms EBP points to the base of the local context, and at *EBP you can find the address of the base of the calling context. ESP points to EBP-SIZE_OF_LOCAL_CONTEXT, different compilers usually compute that size in a different way.

As far as I can see, you are implementig some sort of "fibers". If you are working on Win32, there is aready a set of function that implements in a safe way this functionality (see "fibers"). On linux I suggest you to have a look to "libfiber".

Regards

Comment: the &stck should have be stck. I did the mistake will copying.

Actually I am trying to implement a simple user-thread library.

The mt_sched() takes a new thread from the thread list(the code for which I have not shown), if the state of the thread is NEW, it should allocate the stack to it and starting running the new_fn() on the newly allocated stack.

As the mt_sched will be at the bottom of the stack of each thread.
Platform is x86 Linux.
In the code shown the BP points to the highest address(bottom of the stack) in the stack. I think it's placement is correct.

Comment: Hi! Why that "sp-500"? It sounds to me a bit arbitrary. By the way, I suggest you to create anyway a (pseudo)valid stack frame at the bottom of the stack, and make EBP point to it instead, so debugger commands like gdb's "bt" can show you a reasonable call trace. Bye!